# GAMS Model and implementing parameters and variables

Tags: gams-math

I have a question im trying to answer, i wrote out each requirement but im struggling to implement it in GAMs. I am very new to GAMS and not sure where each variable goes. Where am i going wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8972q.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrO1U.png)

```
    
Sets   
       i   pump capacity 
       j   pump rate  / 1-10 / ;
Parameters
       a(i)  capacity of plant i in cases
         
       b(j)  pump capacity 
        ;
Table  d(i,j) 
    PUMP    MAXIMUM (GAL/MIN)   COST ($/GAL/MIN)    FROM WELL
1   1100                         0.05          1
2   1100                    0.05    2
3   1100    0.05    3
4   1500    0.07    1
5   1500    0.07    2
6   1500    0.07    3
7   2500    0.13    1
8   2500    0.13    2
9   2500    0.13    3
10  2500    0.13    3
;



Variables
     x(i,j) 
     z        ;
Positive variables x ;
Equations
     cost        
     supply(i)   
     demand(j)    ;
cost ..        z  =e=  sum((i,j), c(i,j)*x(i,j)) ;
supply(i) ..   sum(j, x(i,j))  =l=  a(i) ;
demand(j) ..   sum(i, x(i,j))  =g=  b(j) ;
Model transport /all/ ;
Solve transport using LP minimizing z ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Sets   
       i pump plans   / 1*10 /
       k wells /1*3/;
Parameters
WL(k) "limits on wells on GAL/MIN"
       /1 3000,
        2 2500,
        3 7000/

MaxGM(i) "limits on pump plans on GAL/MIN"
       /1 1100,
        2 1100,
        3 1100,
        4 1500,
        5 1500,
        6 1500,
        7 2500,
        8 2500,
        9 2500,
        10 2500/
PlanCost(i) "plan costs per GAL/MIN"
       /1 0.05,
        2 0.05,
        3 0.05,
        4 0.07,
        5 0.07,
        6 0.07,
        7 0.13,
        8 0.13,
        9 0.13,
        10 0.13/ 
         ;
         
display MaxGM, PlanCost;
Table d(i,k) "States if plan i is located in well k"
    1   2   3  
1   1
2       1
3           1
4   1
5       1
6           1
7   1
8       1
9           1
10          1
;

scalar MinOutput /10000/;


Variables
     x(i) 
     z        ;
Positive variables x ;
Equations
     cost        
     supply(i)
     supply2(k)
     demand    ;
cost ..        z  =e=  sum((i), PlanCost(i)*x(i)) ;
supply(i) ..   x(i)  =l=  MaxGM(i) ;
supply2(k) ..   sum(i$d(i,k), x(i))  =l=  WL(k) ;
demand ..   sum(i, x(i))  =g= MinOutput ;
Model transport /all/ ;
Solve transport using LP minimizing z ;

display x.l;
```

Results are:

1 - 1100
2 - 1100
3 - 1100
4 - 1500
5 - 1400
6 - 1500
9 - 2300